# Enable and disable individual interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers

I am working on timer interrupts and external interrupts.
for external interrupts I understood the functions like attachInterrupt. detachinterrupt for individual interrupts ,noInterrupts() and  interrupts() can be used to enable and disable all interrupts at a time.

But How to enable and disable timer interrupts??

I am writing a code for alarm clock and snooze button. So what I want is
1) whenever alarm time is equal to watch time, start a timer for 5 minutes and a buzzer buzzes.
2) whenever I press the snooze button,  another timer starts and after 30 seconds a buzzer beeps. again I press snooze and again the timer starts and after 30 seconds buzzer beeps.
3) But after 5 minutes of the first timer, both timer interrupts gets disabled as now I dont want any buzzer.

I know how to initialize the timer in setup function, and I am getting the buzzes every 30 seconds. I also know that interrupts will come according to the timer value and I need to call the function after a fix number of counts or 30 seconds or 5 minutes.

But I dont know how to disable and enable timer interrupts wherever I want in code.

Comment: Why are you using timer interrupts for this? A software timer (based on `millis()`) seems more appropriate, as you cannot program a hardware timer to fire more than about 4.2 seconds into the future.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have just read about the millis() and I think that it'll be more useful. I'll try to do my project using millis and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

- Step 1: Read the datasheet for the chip.
- Step 2: Find the registers that control the timers and their interrupts.
- Step 3: Set or clear the relevant bits in those registers.

For example, the [ATMega328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) has the `TIMSK1` register for Timer 1, which has three bits related to interrupts:

> - **Bit 2 – OCIE1B: Timer/Counter1, Output Compare B Match Interrupt Enable**
>
> When this bit is written to one, and the I-flag in the status register is set (interrupts globally enabled), the Timer/Counter1
>   output compare B match interrupt is enabled. The corresponding interrupt vector (see Section 11. “Interrupts” on page 49) is
>   executed when the OCF1B flag, located in TIFR1, is set.
>
> - **Bit 1 – OCIE1A: Timer/Counter1, Output Compare A Match Interrupt Enable**
>
> When this bit is written to one, and the I-flag in the status register is set (interrupts globally enabled), the Timer/Counter1
>   output compare A match interrupt is enabled. The corresponding interrupt vector (see Section 11. “Interrupts” on page 49) is
>   executed when the OCF1A flag, located in TIFR1, is set.
>
> - **Bit 0 – TOIE1: Timer/Counter1, Overflow Interrupt Enable**
>
> When this bit is written to one, and the I-flag in the status register is set (interrupts globally enabled), the Timer/Counter1
>   overflow interrupt is enabled. The corresponding interrupt vector (see Section 11. “Interrupts” on page 49) is executed when
>   the TOV1 flag, located in TIFR1, is set.

So to turn off the Compare B Match interrupt you can use:

```
TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << 2);
```

And to turn it on again:

```
TIMSK1 |= (1 << 2);
```

Both Timer 0 and Timer2 have a `TIMSKx` register which works in the same way.